# Undefined control sequence GNU C Library manual texinfo.tex

Tags: errors

I am new to LaTeX. I wanted to compile the documentation file from GNU C Library texinfo.tex. There I encountered the following error message. Could someone please tell me how to fix it? To compile I used the option pdflatex + makeindex + bibtex.

```
texinfo.tex  2211  Undefined control sequence.
                   \resetmathfonts ...font 2=\tensy \textfont \itfam 
                                                       =\tenit \textfont \slfam =...
                   l.2211 \definetextfontsizexi
```

The file texinfo.tex is in folder manual of the tarball http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.22.tar.gz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `glibc` manual uses [`texinfo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) (not LaTeX) and the file `texinfo.tex` provides some `TeX` (not `LaTeX`) macros. You have to use `texi2dvi` or `texi2pdf` to create the manual. Try:

```
$ texi2pdf libc.texinfo
```

Also: There should be a `make` target in the `Makefile`. In the root directory of the glibc source try something like:

```
$ make pdf
```

And: You could just download it: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/